# Linux кодировка русских сообщений скриптов python в командной строке в виде абракадабры

Tags: python, linux, bash, utf-8

В командной строке скрипты пайтон выводят сообщения на русском языке в виде абракадабры

[image]

Локаль ютф русский установлена:

[image]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы русские сообщения выводились на русском языке?

Comment: Через окно putty или напрямую в терминале? Как вариант еще `export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8`

Comment: Нужно код смотреть, откуда данные приходят. Возможно там requests, и просто надо `response.encoding = "utf-8"` поставить

Comment: Замени картинку текстом

Comment: вероятно запустил виндовый скрипт на линуксе, где-то там указание на кодировку. надо убрать, если не создаст новых проблем.